# Bootstrap modal not rendering form elements properly

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal in which i am trying to display a form.But all those form elements are not rendering properly.
Here is code for modal-

```
<div id="mypartymodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1000px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  New Party Entry</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form  class="form-horizontal partyform"  id="partyform">
           <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Party name:</label>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="party_name" name="party_name" >
      </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

     <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Opening bal:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="op_bal" name="op_bal" placeholder="Op.bal">
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Vat:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vat" name="vat" placeholder="Vat no.">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

     <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Cst:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cst" name="cst" placeholder="Cst no.">
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Pan:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pan" name="pan" placeholder="Pan no.">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Service Tax no.:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ser" name="ser" placeholder="Service Tax no.">
      </div>
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter address"></textarea>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

     <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Email-id:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email-id">
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Mobile:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mob" name="mob" placeholder="Enter contact number">
      </div>
    </div> 

        </form>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="saveparty" name="saveparty">save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I know i should have created a fiddle for such question,but seriously i tried but it is not working,so i am asking it like this.
Please let me know how would i get all my form elements rendered properly on a modal and in a compact way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your code in jfiddle.

Comment: i tried that but it is not working...

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: in creating a fiddle or in my question?

Comment: creating a fiddle

Comment: well in that i am using a button to trigger a modal but when i click on the button nothing shows up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123525/discussion-between-jeetdaloneboy-and-payal-suthar).

Comment: @payal_suthar Everything is working fine.. https://jsfiddle.net/kb9amv1t/

Comment: @payal_suthar check browser console, may be you forgot to add jQuery before `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: add full html code in question @payal_suthar

Comment: yeah got it..i had just placed the jquery.js below bootstrap.js..thanks to @JeetDaloneboy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the jquery link before bootstrap js file link. like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```